# Structuring a Nodejs, express & ejs app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

Wondering what is the best way to structure the ejs part of the application,
here is my current structure.

inside maindir/

- index.js // starts the application
- node-modules
- homepage/ // i would be creating a folder like this for each view
- partials/ // has common components navbar.ejs and footer.ejs.

inside the maindir/homepage/

- routes.js // has the app.get/post/put/deletes({"/homepage", controller.*})'s
- controller.js // exports the controllers
- models.js // exports mongo models
- ejs/

inside the /maindir/homepage/ejs/

- app.ejs // imports common partials e.g. navbar & footer from partials/ & homepage specific components from components/
- components/

is this a decent way to structure an application? specifically the importing from the partials/ directory into each new view or is there a better way to achieve this goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this a decent way to structure an application?

The question/answer is entirely subjective.

My answer will be based on what *most* developers do.

Traditionally, the root folder structure of an Express application is the following:

```
example
├── app.js
├── controllers
├── models
├── public
└── views
```

As you can see this is the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern. An alternative pattern to the above, which is common in frontend applications, is organizing it by feature/components:

```
example
├── app.js
├── auth
│   ├── auth-controller.js
│   ├── auth-view.ejs
│   └── auth-model.js
├── notification
│   ├── notification-controller.js
│   ├── notification-view.ejs
│   └── notification-model.js
└── topic
```

It boils to your personal preference or what your team decides.

Comment: First is good, however controllers is often renamed to routes. I don't prefer second.

Answer (score 0):

Using [express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) can be a good starting point if you are new to setting up an `express` app.